# Is there is a built-in dialog we can use for "Select Start Menu Folder" in Wix 3.11

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is there is a built-in dialog we can use for "**Select Start Menu Folder**" in Wix 3.11, to allow users to edit the target shortcut folder name and location ?

My code correctly creates the shortcuts in a predetermined sub-folder of the default **ProgramMenuFolder**, but I want to give users the ability to change this as they like.

I am using the "**WixUI_InstallDir**" dialog set.

Whilst there are many questions on dealing with creating shortcuts in different locations with Wix, I cannot find any about how to show a dialog for "Select Start Menu Folder" during installs.